# How to access elements of pointer array in Nim?

Tags: c, nim-lang

I've been stuck on this

```
let aiArray: ptr aiMesh =  sceneptr[].mMeshes[]
```

Here `aiArray` is a pointer to an array (from C).

How can I access the elements like `aiArray[0]`, `aiArray[1]` and stuff?

I tried doing the `aiArray[0]` thing but it didn't work. I also tried to assign it to `array[0..0, aiMesh] = sceneptr[].mMeshes[]` but that won't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cast[ptr UncheckedArray[aiMesh]](myPtr)[0]`

Nim does not treat all pointers as indexable by default so you need to cast to an indexable `ptr UncheckedArray` or write the bindings as such.

Comment: This question has already been answered a while ago on some forum posts:
https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/4865#30459
https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/3296#20759
but I am glad this has been answered on SO since it is better referenced by Google and other search engines.
A little explanation of why Nim does not treat all pointers as indexable by default (not necessarily contiguous memory) would make the answer even better.